# Image of the union is the union of the images

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

$$ f\left(\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}\right) = \bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda)$$

Let $b \in f(\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda})$
$\rightarrow b=f(a)$ for some $a \in (\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda})$.

Since $a \in (\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}) \rightarrow a \in A_{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda \in \wedge$.

Since $b=f(a)$, then $b \in f(A_{\lambda})$ for some $\lambda \in \wedge$.

$\rightarrow b \in \bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda)$
$\rightarrow f(\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}) \subset \bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda)$.

I used a similar argument to prove $\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda) \subset f(\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda})$.

Which shows $ f(\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}) = \bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda)$.

Please let me know if this is valid.

Comment: The one direction looks fine, I can't comment on the other direction unless you provide details.  But it seems like you have a handle on this.

Comment: Thank you for your insight!

Comment: @JamesSnell What about the intersection.

Comment: The same set-up, but using the intersection instead?

Answer (score 2):

That's fine. For the sake of completeness, a proof of $\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda} f(A_\lambda) \subseteq f(\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_{\lambda})$ follows:
\begin{alignat*}{3}
 b \in \bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda} f(A_\lambda) 
 \quad\Rightarrow&\quad
 b \in f(A_\lambda) \text{ for some } \lambda \in \Lambda 
 &&\quad\Rightarrow\quad
 b = f(a) \text{ for some } a \in A_\lambda \text{ and } \lambda \in \Lambda
 \\
 \quad\Rightarrow&\quad b = f(a) \text{ for some } a \in \bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} A_\lambda
 &&\quad\Rightarrow\quad
 b \in f(\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}A_\lambda).
\end{alignat*}

Roughly speaking, the proof essentially relies on the fact that you can switch harmlessly the order of the two existential quantifiers in "for some $a \in A_\lambda$ and $\lambda \in \Lambda$".